One-dimensional subspace spanned by a vector of elementary symmetric functions
For a non-empty finite set $I\in\mathbb{R}$, the $i$'th elementary symmetric function is defined as follows
$$e_i(I) := \sum_{X\in \binom{I}{i}}\prod_{x\in X}x$$
where $\binom{I}{i}:=\{X\subseteq I\;:\; |X|=i\}.$
It is well known that for any non-empty finite sets $I,I'\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $|I|=d=|I'|$, $I=I'$ if and only if $e_i(I)=e_i(I')$ for every $i=1,...,d$.
Let $d,w\in\mathbb{N}$ with $w>2d$.
For brevity, let $[w]:=\{1,2,\dots,w\}$.
Then, for $I\in\binom{[w]}{d}$, I define
$$e(I):= (e_1(I),e_2(I),\dots,e_{d-1}(I))\in \mathbb{Q}^{d-1}.$$
Notice that I omit the case when $i=d$ here, even though the size of $I$ is $d$ and $e_d(I)$ is well-defined.
So, it is possible to have different (or even, disjoint) sets $I,I'\in\binom{[w]}{d}$ such that $e(I)=e(I')$.
I am interested in the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $e(I)$, in other words, the following set:
$$<e(I)>\;:=\{k\cdot e(I)\;:\;k\in \mathbb{Q}\}.$$
Now, pick $I,I'\in \binom{[w]}{d}$ with $I\cap I'=\emptyset$.
Generally, $<e(I)>=<e(I')>$ does not imply $e(I)=e(I')$.
But, I notice that when $d$ is not that small, it is likely that the implication holds.
This "the implication holds", means, for every disjoint $I,I'\in\binom{[w]}{d}$, if $e(I)=k\cdot e(I')$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $k=1$.
For instance, when $d=4$ and by taking $w=23$, I examined every disjoint pair $I,I'\in\binom{[w]}{d}$ by computation and found out that there is no $k\in\mathbb{Q}$ other than $k=1$ fulfills $e(I)=k\cdot e(I')$.
Of course in this case, maybe if $w$ is sufficiently large, then it is possible to find such disjoint pair that fulfill $e(I)=k\cdot e(I')$ for $k\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{1\}$.
But, if $d$ is larger, let's say for instance $d=5$, I think it is more unlikely to find such disjoint pair (compared to the case when $d=4$) that fulfill $e(I)=k\cdot e(I')$ for $k\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{1\}$.
So, do you have any idea on how to solve the following problem?
Problem: Is there any $d\in\mathbb{N}$ such that: for any integer $w>2d$, there is no disjoint pair $I,I'\in\binom{[w]}{d}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{1\}$ that fulfils $e(I)=k\cdot e(I')$?
If there is no such $d$, is it possible that for any given $d\in\mathbb{N}$, we find a value $U(d)$ such that: for every $2d<w\leq U(d)$, there is no disjoint pair $I,I'\in\binom{[w]}{d}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{1\}$ that fulfill $e(I)=k\cdot e(I')$?
